# Unable to generate pdf using mpdf in php 7.1

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, mpdf

i try to generate a simple pdf using mpdf.

This what I used:

```
1) php 7.1
2) Laravel 5.3
3) mpdf dev-master version
```

This is how i write the mpdf code.

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
    $mpdf->Output("test.pdf", "D");
```

But it will not download and return to me some weird response. But it executed the code successfully.

**CHROME**:

[image: Chrome error]

**FIREFOX**:

[image: firefox error]

Can someone help me? Kind of stuck with this whole day long.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

1. Make sure your project meets mpdf requirements and that all dependencies and php library are installed.

   Requires

   ```
   ext-mbstring: *
   setasign/fpdi: 1.6.*
   php: ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0
   ext-gd: *
   psr/log: ^1.0
   paragonie/random_compat: ^2.0
   ```

   Requires (Dev)

   ```
   phpunit/phpunit: ^5.0
   mockery/mockery: ^0.9.5
   squizlabs/php_codesniffer: ^2.7.0
   tracy/tracy: ^2.4
   phpstan/phpstan: ^0.6.4
   ```
2. The code below works for me:

   ```
   $storage_path = storage_path();
   $mypdf = new mPDF(['tempDir' =>  $storage_path . '/app', 'margin_left' => 0, 'margin_right' => 0,
   'margin_top' => 0, 'margin_bottom' => 0, 'margin_header' => 0, 'margin_footer' => 0]);
   $mypdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
   $mypdf->WriteHTML(file_get_contents($job_letter_css), 1);
   $mypdf->WriteHTML($content, 2);

   $structure = "./job_letters/{$id}/";
   if (file_exists($structure)) {
       $file_name = $structure ."job_offer_letter.pdf";
   } else {
       mkdir($structure, 0777, true);
       $file_name = $structure ."job_offer_letter.pdf";
   }
   $mypdf->Output($file_name, 'F');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is in a controller, you may have to `return` something, so add a `return`:

```
return $mpdf->Output("test.pdf", "D");
```

If it still does not work, you could try to return it to the browser:

```
return $mpdf->Output("test.pdf", 'I');
```

Side note: there are also a good lib specific to Laravel that works like a charm: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Comment: Hi i tested and it still not working. I try not to use other lib because of the existing legacy code.

Comment: Throw your legacy. Be free as a bird. Sing, Fly, LIVE! :) Ok, sorry if my answer did not helped.